# Collecting previously executed commands using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, centos7

I want to write every previously executed command into a log, this is what I would do if I do it manually:

1. executes `sudo -s`
2. append to /etc/profile the following lines

```bash
export HISTORY_FILE="/var/log/history/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log"
export PROMPT_COMMAND='{
   logfile="$HISTORY_FILE"
   # Create the file if it does not  exist
   touch "$logfile"
   # Set permissions to 666 (rw-rw-rw-)
   chmod 666 "$logfile"
   # Append history entry to the file
   { date "+%Y-%m-%d %T ##### $(who am i | awk "{print \$1\" \"\$2\" \"\$5}") #### 
$(history 1 | { read x cmd; echo "$cmd"; })"; } >> "$logfile"
}'
```

3. executes `source /etc/profile`

This works, now each line of executed command goes to `/var/log/history/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log`.

Now I want to do it with Ansible, so I write a script

```yaml
---
- name: Enable command logging
  hosts: logging_history
  tasks:
    - name: Check if the file contains the logging configuration already
      shell: cat /etc/profile | grep "HISTORY_FILE"
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      failed_when: false
      register: grep_result

    - name: Add logging configuration to /etc/profile
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      when: grep_result.rc > 0
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/profile
        line: |
          export HISTORY_FILE="/var/log/hansight_history/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log"
          export PROMPT_COMMAND='{
              logfile="$HISTORY_FILE"
              # Create the file if it does not  exist
              touch "$logfile"
              # Set permissions to 666 (rw-rw-rw-)
              chmod 666 "$logfile"
              # Append history entry to the file
              { date "+%Y-%m-%d %T ##### $(who am i | awk "{print \$1\" \"\$2\" \"\$5}") #### $(history 1 | { read x cmd; echo "$cmd"; })"; } >> "$logfile"
          }'
    
    - name: mkdir /var/log/hansight_history
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /var/log/hansight_history
        state: directory
        mode: '666'
      become: yes 
      become_method: sudo  

    - name: Source /etc/profile
      shell: source /etc/profile
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
      register: output
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
    - debug: msg="{{ output }}"

    - name: Check if /etc/profile is activated correctly
      command: echo $HISTORY_FILE
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      register: history_file
    - debug: msg="{{ history_file.stdout }}"
```

This script has several issues:

1. permission denied without `sudo`

```bash
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/log/history/2024-02-02.log’: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access ‘/var/log/history/2024-02-02.log’: Permission denied
-bash: /var/log/history/2024-02-02.log: Permission denied
```

2. no commands logged after executing `sudo -s`, to start logging, I have to manually run `source /etc/profile`
3. minor one but it still confuses me: the last task `command: echo $HISTORY_FILE` outputs $HISTORY_FILE instead of its value

```bash
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "$HISTORY_FILE"
}
```

What I expect

1. no commands executed without `sudo -s` need to be logged
2. logging every command executed after `sudo -s`
3. the last task outputs something like

```bash
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "/var/log/history/2024-02-02.log"
}
```